# Error shown in core/Model.php codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, model

I am newbie to Codeigniter and trying to edit fields that are entered in database. Also I am following this tutorial from [CI tutorial](http://www.phpeveryday.com/articles/CodeIgniter-Form-Creating-Beautiful-Form-Code-P263.html) . When I tried to run the site I got the error like

```
Message: Undefined property: Books::$query

Filename: core/Model.php

Line Number: 51
```

But I have not modified any code in core files. My model `book_model.php` is

```
function get($id)
    {
        //echo $id;
        $this->load->database();

       // echo 'sda';
        $query = $this->db->get_where('books',array('id'=>$id));

        echo 'test';
        $a = $this->query->row_array();
        var_dump($a);
        return $a;
    }
```

I can see the echo but `var_dump()` shows nothing.

Comment: Do you have the table books?

Comment: Yes..it exists in database

Comment: Aren't you missing group_name in your $this->load->database() statment?

Comment: @Nitish Have you tried the below answer? I think it could be the problem.

Comment: @raheelshan No load statement is correct. http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/connecting.html However I have never done an app without adding the database to autoload.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your referencing your query result string wrong.

Try:

```
$a = $query->row_array();
```

and your var_dump will work.

Generally in CI you should not echo stuff from your model. Use your controller to fetch data from the model and echo things in your views instead.

Comment: Thank you jtheman...I am able to view the `var_dump()` result at last. Thanks a lot.